# Two way UDP client and server?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, udp, posix

I'm trying to implement a basic file transfer protocol, using UDP. 
I'm using Beej's Guide as a reference, and much of the code I will post is from there.

My program so far has the 'talker' send the name of the file it wants to the 'receiver'.

From there, the reciever checks if the file exists, and if it does, it figures out the size of the file.

Now here is where I run into problems. I need the receiver to send the size of the file to the talker. You can see in my code (links below) how I implemented it. However, the talker just hangs, like it's still waiting for something to be sent.

This makes me think the reciever needs some additional code to allow it to communicate back to the talker, and not just recieve data from it (I'm used to TCP, so excuse my lack of knowledge).

Could someone tell me what code I am missing, or if I am using the functions wrong? It's difficult to follow Beej's guide, and he does not provide an example of a two-way communication.

Thanks, and let me know if you need any more info.

---

Listener: http://pastebin.com/UL1xjDnP

Talker: http://pastebin.com/B2zrXPgZ

---

EDIT: Solved!
Thanks to cnicutar,

I was addressing the server in this code, when i should have addressed the client

`if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0,
    p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1)`

which should be changed to

`if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1)`

Comment: Is the "listener" reporting "listener: file size has been sent" ?

Comment: I'm wondering why UDP? TCP is a much better protocol for transferring files. UDP does not offer such goodies as sequential delivery, resending corrupt data etc. that is key when transferring files.

Comment: Yes, listener is reporting the file size has been sent.
Also i want to learn UDP, i think it's valuable to know both.

Comment: @user974703 I answered below. Also, edit you question and add the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending to the right peer. You are obtaining `p` from `getaddrinfo` and then sending to it. So you are sending the message to yourself.

```
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
/* .... */


numbytes = recvfrom(sockfd, buf, MAXBUFLEN-1 , 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1)

/* .... */
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0,
    p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) == -1)
```

You likely want to send it to "them":

```
if ((numbytes = sendto(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer), 0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_len)) == -1)
```

Comment: bingo! that was the problem. Only thing I notice now is that last letter the talker prints out (of the file size) is garbage. I'm assuming it's because there isn't a \n on the end of the string I was sending?

Comment: @user974703 You probably want to set `\0` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to have your "sender" listen on the same port/ip it's using to send packets to the server. The server can extract the source ip/port from the packet headers, and send its replies there. If you need to use different ports/ips for the replies, then your 'sender' would have to include that information in what it sends over. e.g. "here's your information, send replies to x.x.x.x:yyy"

Comment: It doesn't have to listen. `recvfrom` (which it's already doing) is enough.